Android - Deserialize specific object in data class response with Gson
I have this example json:
{
  "base": {
    "data": "{\"ids\":[\"first-v1\",\"second-v2\"],\"version\":\"1\",\"prettyVersion\":\"v2\",\"updatedAt\":1726669388214}",
    "signature": "aaaaa"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "data": "{\"id\":\"first-v1\",\"name\":\"FIRST\",\"version\":\"v1\",\"myValues\":{\"screen\":{\"title\":\"THIS IS TITLE\",\"dataItems\":[{\"id\":\"ID:\",\"text\":\"TEXT\",\"type\":\"RED\"}]},\"SecondScreen\":{\"title\":\"Second Title\",\"subtitle\":\"Second subtitle\"}}}",
      "signature": "bbb"
    },
    {
      "data": "{\"id\":\"second-v1\",\"name\":\"SECOND\",\"version\":\"v1\",\"myValues\":{\"screen\":{\"title\":\"THIS IS TITLE\",\"dataItems\":[{\"id\":\"ID:\",\"text\":\"TEXT\",\"type\":\"BLUE\"}]},\"SecondScreen\":{\"title\":\"Second Title\",\"subtitle\":\"Second subtitle\"}}}",
      "signature": "bbb"
    }
  ]
}

And I have a data class representing the response, lets call it
  data class MyResponse(
    @SerializedName("items") val items: List<Items>? = null,
    @SerializedName("base") val base: Base? = null
) : Serializable

inside Items I have another data class representing Items and so..
I want to deserialize dataItems list according to the attribute type, for that I have this class:
open class Color(
    @SerializedName("id") open val id: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("text") open val text: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("type") open val type: String? = null,
) {}

data class Blue(
    override val id: String? = null,
    override val text: String? = null,
    override val type: String? = DataItemTypes.Blue.name
) : Color(id, text, type)

data class Red(
    override val id: String? = null,
    override val text: String? = null,
    val createCircle: String? = null,
    override val type: String? = DataItemTypes.Red.name
) : Color(id, text, type) 

I tried creating a Gson with custom adapter, but it has to be on the Response class and I can't do it on the DataItems class. from all my tries I found that I will have to "catch" the response, dig through the json object, find dataItems and replace it.
I wonder if there's a better way to deserialize only the DataItem class.
Thanks

I suggest using serialization library that actually supports kotlin.

It sounds like you are looking for "polymorphic deserialization". But as mentioned by @Pawel might be better to use a JSON library with proper Kotlin support, such as Jackson or kotlinx.serialization, see also the warning in Gson's README.
